# yii 2 sluggable behavior arabic

Tags: yii2, arabic, slug

I used Yii Sluggable Behavior and it worked fine for English, but if I write Arabic language in the name text field and create a new entry, the value of the slug column in the database is empty.

```
public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                [
                    'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                    'attribute' => 'name',
                    'ensureUnique'=>true,
                    'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
                ],
            ];
        }
```

Does anybody know how to make it support Arabic and other languages? If not, is there an extension that do the job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://github.com/zelenin/yii2-slug-behavior with transliteration options.

Comment: @Beowulfenator Zelenin slug behaviour transform the word, example "أحمد " =>."ahmd ", I don't want that I want the words to stay as is. example: ' مرحبا بك ' => ' مرحبا-بك '

Answer (score 2):

Creating a slug usually involves using a regular expression to exclude unwanted characters that are not compatible with the normal URL format.

Regular expressions used in `preg_replace` or `preg_match` usually are written to support English slugs, thus excluding all other types of characters like Arabic.

I suggest that you write your own slugging function with an appropriate character range including arabic characters. Something like this:

```
$slug = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9ء-ي _\-]/u", "", $title);
```

This will exclude all characters other than the ones in the ranges a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the Arabic alphabet. It will also keep underscores, dashes and spaces, which you can replace later on if you need.